# Jsoup connection 501 error

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How can I establish a connection with Jsoup in order to fill & send a form?

The website looks similar to this:

```
          <form action="the.form" method="post"
                enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                name="start_form"
                autocomplete="off">
             <input type="hidden" value="8F5EB4CD93CAB4E093EF7C1C733791FC" name="session" />
             <input type="text" value="" name="number" />
             <div class="right">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
             </div>
          </form>
```

What I tried:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(DUMMY_URL).data("number", "123456789", "session", 
"6F80A198EC4B46B4848897A33ACAC3E8").header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded").userAgent("Mozilla").post();
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 501 error loading URL https://www.theurl.com
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:414)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:391)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:157)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:152)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to submit text via forms using JSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644168/how-to-submit-text-via-forms-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already answered this on [THIS thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139178/jsoup-cookies-for-https-scraping/10533366#10533366).

If you have any further doubts, just ask.