# Using JSoup to scrape Google Weather Results

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get the weather condition from google web page, and there are a tag on the HTML elements `wob_tm`, I tried to get the value, but always i get an exception

```
 try {
      Document  document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.jo/webhp?hl=en#hl=en-JO&q=amman+weather").get();
      Element temp = document.getElementById("wob_tm");
      System.out.println(temp.text()); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what Exception do you get?

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: Have you tried printing out the whole document to your LogCat to check what you're actually getting?

Comment: actually u got not proper document response check ur response

Comment: @freddieptf 
Yes I did print the whole document, it only prints the content of the home page of google.com  not the page of the results , what is the problem ?

Comment: @jitendraparmar yeah I only got response from google.com page not my url

Comment: ok i try to get the result

Comment: @jitendraparmar How ?? this is my problem

Comment: direct not get response because in request pass so many things.

Comment: @jitendraparmar can you show me how ? sorry I didn't get what do you mean

Comment: Some sites just don't get scraped as easily and directly as that. Read this https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644168/how-to-submit-text-via-forms-using-jsoup

Comment: @freddieptf its right so,try to scrape with make own request and use post method of jsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was an error in the query and I should define a user agent

```
Document doc = Jsoup
    .connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=mario");
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
    .timeout(5000).get();
```